# attempt to invoke virtual function

Tags: java, android

The error is :- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.example.pratikrathi.registerapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)

how to solve this? why i am getting this error? help me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button register_button;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("RegisterApp");


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {

        sendToLogin();


    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_logout_btn:
            logOut();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings_btn:
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void sendToLogin() {
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
    finish();
}

private void logOut() {

    mAuth.signOut();
    sendToLogin();

}
}
```

The Xml layout file is included below.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.pratikrathi.registerapp.MainActivity">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:title="RegisterApp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It would seem that the `<Toolbar>` with ID `toolbar` is not in the `activity_main` layout, either directly, or in an `<include>`d layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to set Toolbar title like this and also check your toolbaar id**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("RegisterApp");
```

Comment: checkout I have included xml file

Comment: add this : android:id="@+id/toolbar" in your toolbar xml

Comment: yeah that solved  my problem... thank you